# When may we need to use runOnUiThread in android application?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a code sample that uses this function to run a thread `runOnUiThread`. why and when may we need to use it?

### edit

What about to use `AsyncTask` class, what's the `pros` and `cons`??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use `runOnUiThread()` when you want to update your UI from a Non-UI Thread. For eg- If you want to update your UI from a background Thread. You can also use `Handler` for the same thing.

**From the Docs -**

> Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is
>   the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current
>   thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue
>   of the UI thread.

**Syntax -**

```
       Activity_Name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your stuff to update the UI

            }
        });
```

**Update -**

```
AsyncTask -
```

> If you want to do some `Network operation` or anything that blocks
>   your UI in that case AsyncTask is best options. There are several
>   other ways for performing the same Background Operations as you can
>   use `Service`, `IntentService` also for doing Background Operations.
>   Using AsyncTask will help you doing your UI work and also won't block
>   your UI until your background Operation is going on.

**From the Docs -**

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

Comment: What about to use `AsyncTask` class, what's the pros and cons ??

Comment: I didn't find anything related to `AsyncTask` in your question.

Comment: If handler can do the same thing like `runOnUiThread`, why to use the later?

Comment: Hidden pitfalls of async task http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/

Answer (score 1):

To update `userinterface` from thread you need to use `runOnUiThread`. But using `asynctask` is better than using `runonuithread`. [android-runonuithread-vs-asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296539/android-runonuithread-vs-asynctask) this link can help you