# Admob interstial loadAd function too slow

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I recently added an interstitial ad using Admob with the Google Play services library (which is still pretty buggy BTW).

The interstitial is working well but the following call:

```
// Begin loading interstitial
interstitial.loadAd(adInterstitialRequest);
```

is very slow, it can delay up to 2 seconds the first launch of my app.

What could I do to avoid this? I followed exactly the example provided by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced).

**FYI** I tried to load the ad in the background using an `AsyncTask` but it does not seem possible to do it:

```
03-23 15:50:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3572): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: loadAd must be called on the main UI thread.
```

Thank you

Comment: How about using RunOnUIThread from your background task. Usage explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10135376/1683141

Comment: What I need is to avoid using this UI Thread actually, this answer can't help me.

Comment: Having the same issue, introducing the new AdMob causes a massive delay in loading the App on some devices. About 3 seconds for Banner Ad and another 3 for Interstitial. This is just calling loadAd not actually displaying the Ad.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the ad listener?
try this:

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(Your-ad-id-here);

// Create ad request.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

// Begin loading your interstitial.
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        displayInterstitial();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the slow down of your app start, delay the initialization until your activity has been loaded and is visible:

> ```
>              mAdView.postDelayed(
>                      new Runnable() {
>                          @Override
>                          public void run() {
>                              mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
>                          }
>                      }, 500
>              );
> ```

See also [AdMob causes delay in displaying fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819328/2154836)