# AdMob causes delay in displaying fragments

Tags: android, admob

My app is using navigation drawer. Upon clicking on the item in the drawer, it will display a fragment. And I put the AdMob code inside the fragment, as displayed below:

```
public class MenuIncome extends Fragment {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_income, container, false);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.destroy();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Before I put the AdMob code, my fragment would be displayed instantaneously upon clicking an item on the navigation drawer. But after I put the AdMob code, when I click an item on the drawer, sometimes my app would be liked freezed for up to 1 second, then only the fragment (with the ad) would be displayed.

Why do this happen? I thought AdView have already load its ad asynchronously.

Comment: Why are you destroying your AdView after loading the ad. This will undoubtedly be causing problems.

Comment: because it seems all the tutorial do this.

Comment: I have never seen a tutorial do that. And most definitely the ones by Admob don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

The first call of `loadAd(..)` takes some time for the initialization of admob and this freezes your fragment when loading. 
You can delay the initialization until your fragment has been loaded and is visible:

> ```
>              mAdView.postDelayed(
>                      new Runnable() {
>                          @Override
>                          public void run() {
>                              mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
>                          }
>                      }, 500
>              );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried instead to place the `AdView` in your parent `Activity` which is hosting the `Fragment`?

The below setup is how I use ads in my application, which also uses a navigation drawer and multiple fragments. There is no delay at all in loading the fragments. In fact, at times the fragment will load well before the ad, depending on the case.

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>

    ...

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think I could do like yours. Not all my fragments has AdView in it. Furthermore what I don't understand is, from the code above, it seems you load the ads in your MainActivity. How then the individual fragments below it load the ads then?