# How to execute success method in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an Android+Firebase app but since I'm new to both techlogies I'm having a problem regarding async calls and I haven't found the solution yet so hope you can help me.

I have the following snippet in my Activity's `onCreate` method:

```
final ArrayList<AssetLocation> assetsLocations = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference assetsLocationReference = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.ASSETSLOCATION_REFERENCE);
        assetsLocationReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                ArrayList<String> assetsLocationSpinner = new ArrayList<String>();
                // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Getting the data from snapshot
                    AssetLocation assetsLocation = postSnapshot.getValue(AssetLocation.class);
                    assetsLocations.add(AssetLocation);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

I also have a pretty similar call but instead of getting **Locations**, I'm getting **Types**.

After this code (inside the onCreate method as well), I'm calling `setScreenInfo` which is a function to fill both spinners (and do more stuff) with said data but since it is an async call, the spinners are blank when I execute it.

How can I execute `setScreenInfo` once the calls are made? I tried with `.once()/.on()` but it's not being recognised by Android Studio as a function.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the asynchronously behaviour, you need to move the declaration of the `assetsLocations` ArrayList:

```
final ArrayList<AssetLocation> assetsLocations = new ArrayList<>();
```

inside the `onDataChange()` method, as `assetsLocationSpinner` ArrayList is. So remember, `onDataChange` is always called `asynchronously`. This means that the statement that adds objects of `AssetLocation` class to the list is executed before `onDataChange` has been called. That's why your list is empty outside that method.

For other approach, please visit this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576441/querying-data-from-firebase) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723139/wait-firebase-async-retrive-data-in-android).

Hope ot helps.

Answer (score 1):

> After this code (inside the onCreate method as well), I'm calling setScreenInfo which is a function to fill both spinners (and do more stuff) with said data but since it is an async call, the spinners are blank when I execute it.

You aren't allowed to modify the UI from a background thread.  Normally I would make a call to `runOnUIThread`, passing a new Runnable() and a `final` copy of the data I want to pass.

```
        final String myData = "updateData";

        ActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // use myData to update UI
            }
        });
```

However, it seems like there's a migration to `AsyncTask` : [Converting runOnUiThread to AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291215/converting-runonuithread-to-asynctask)

I personally still use `runOnUIThread`.  It's more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread:

```
thread = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            //background tasks

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //UI tasks
                }
            });
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
    thread.start();`
```

Or you can use Firebase Multi Query method.
link:  [Only load layout when firebase calls are complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173569/only-load-layout-when-firebase-calls-are-complete)