# Android difference between Thread and AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, fragment

I've been trying to connect to a server to retrieve some data. First thing came to my mind was to create a thread to connect asynchronously.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // retrieve data
    }
}).run();
```

But the weird thing is that the thread I created worked synchronous with UI thread and I got a network exception so I ended up using AsyncTask. Do you guys know what could cause a thread to work non asynchronously with the UI thread? My class extends to a fragment.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480206/asynctask-vs-thread-in-android

Comment: The link tells the difference between two of them but I was wondering why I could not do a background work in a thread, since both should be used for asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 5):

Your must start your thread with `start()` and not `run()` in order to start the new thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // retrieve data
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Yes I think that was the problem. But what's the difference between run and start? I could only see the exception throwing between them.

Comment: run() runs on the same thread as the caller's, whereas start() starts a new Thread.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu when you use `Thread.run()` the `run()` method of that Runnable that you passed to the Thread constructor is called in the same thread.