# What is the best between Thread and AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

what is the best for working with java web service and Android client between thread and asynctask  ?

Comment: Also it's depend on your requirement .

Comment: Original post you can get here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480206/asynctask-vs-thread-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AsyncTask for:

```
Simple network operations which do not require downloading a lot of data
Disk-bound tasks that might take more than a few milliseconds
```

Use Java threads for:

```
Network operations which involve moderate to large amounts of data (either uploading or downloading)
High-CPU tasks which need to be run in the background
Any task where you want to control the CPU usage relative to the GUI thread
```

For Thread

> synchronization with the main thread if you post back results to the
>   user interface No default for canceling the thread No default thread
>   pooling No default for handling configuration changes in Android