# Android - Threads or Tasks

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin, task

What's the difference (if any) between:

```
new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() => {
    Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
        recyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);
    });
})).Start();
```

and:

```
await Task.Run(() => recyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18480297