# WiFi direct- using a simple thread for server side part

Tags: java, android, runnable, wifi-direct

I want to make an android  wifi direct app to transfer data. And I'm following wifidirect demo tutorial. 
Now I have connected two devices. In that tutorial a asyncTask is used to server side part in the onConnectionavailableInfo() method and under :

```
If( info.groupFormed &&  info.isGroupOwner)
```

And inside that asyncTask do InBackground  :

```
ServerSocket server = new ...
Socket socket = server.accept()
...
```

(These lines of code is just for addressing)

I want to know can I simply and directly use a thread and a runnable in it inside the onConnectionInfoAvailable for accepting data from client?
Can I use server.accept into a runnable without causing error?
Or I have to use a asyncTask.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480206/asynctask-vs-thread-in-android ?

Comment: Thanks. I read it. But still I don't know which one is fit my target. I want to stream videos and transfer images.

Comment: I'd advice you to use AsyncTask...