# Most concise way to create an Async Task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to perform a very simple operation that involve network. I know that this must be done with an Async Task, because run a task that involves Network operations on main thread is bad.

Since is pretty verbose using the classic way

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //to do
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //to do
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

for a method static method invocation that must download only few bits

I'm wondering if there is some more concise form or alternative that I could use.

Comment: You do not have to override all those menber functions. Only doInBackground() will do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `AsyncTask`. It is just a convenience to use because it already has callback methods.

You can create a new `Thread` and execute your network call there.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to create a worker thread. It depends on what are you doing with network.

- If you just want to do **simple network operations** such as download some JSON data then get it back to update UI: use `AsyncTask`.
- If you want to do **long network operations** which involve moderate to large amounts of data (either uploading or downloading): use `Thread`.
- If you want to continuously send/receive message to/from the Internet, use `HandlerThread`.

So in conclusion: `AsyncTask` is already the **simplest and easiest** to use. Beside, you don't need to override all methods, just override `doInBackGround()` and `onPostExecute()` if you want to receive data.

See: [Asynctask vs Thread in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480206/asynctask-vs-thread-in-android)

Comment: @greenapps what do you mean?

Comment: Well what do you advice for them?

Comment: @greenapps do you see my conclusion? I'm cannot just give advice without telling WHY!.

Comment: @greenapps it will take you 10sec to open the link and have your answer (even if i agree that should have been copied in the answer)

Comment: For `long network operations` where you advise a Thread i would use a Service. Wel... a Thread in a Service ;-).

Comment: @greenapps It depends. `Service` a very different context to threading.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `AsyncTask.execute(() -> { /* network operations */ });`, the downside is you don't get any of the callbacks so I tend to only use this when prototyping or with *very* simple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an anonymous class inside a method:

```
public void asyncOperation () {
    new AsyncTask<Task, Void, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Your background operation, network, database, etc
            return true;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```