# How do I put AsyncTask code to Thread Handler

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-handler

I'm trying to develop an android app that could list all app and their cache's.
But I'm facing a problem that whenever I tap on generated list I'm getting force close because 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has 
changed but ListView did not receive a notification. 
Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, 
but only from the UI thread.`

So I'm trying to convert my AsyncTask code to Thread Hadler, can any body please help me out with this problem. Here is my code

```
public class Messages extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    msgList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MessageList);

    applicationCacheSize = new ArrayList<Long>();
    applicationPackageName = new ArrayList<String>();
    applicationName = new ArrayList<String>();

    cacheApplicationName = new ArrayList<String>();

    details = new ArrayList<MessageDetails>();
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(Messages.this, "Loading..",
                    "Please Wait", true, false);
        }// End of onPreExecute method

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    Context mContext = createPackageContext(packageInfo.packageName, CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
                    PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                    ApplicationInfo ai;
                    try {
                        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( mContext.getPackageName(), 0);
                    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
                        ai = null;
                    }
                    final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
                    appNames.add(applicationName);
                    appPackageName.add(packageInfo.packageName);
                    appCache.add(mContext.getCacheDir());

                }
                catch (NameNotFoundException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            for(int i=0; i<appCache.size(); i++)
            {

                try {
                    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

                    Method getPackageSizeInfo;

                    getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
                        "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);
                    getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, appPackageName.get(i), new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {

                            @Override
                            public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                                throws RemoteException {



                                final String title;
                                ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;



                                    try {
                                        applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(pStats.packageName, 0);
                                        title = (String)((applicationInfo != null) ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) : "???");

                                        MessageDetails Detail;
                                        Detail = new MessageDetails();
                                        Detail.setIcon(getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon( pStats.packageName ));
                                        Detail.setName(title);
                                        Detail.setSub("Cache Size -> "+(((pStats.cacheSize/1024) > 0)?(pStats.cacheSize/1024):"No Cache"));
                                        details.add(Detail);
                                        if((pStats.cacheSize) != 0 )
                                        {
                                            cacheApplicationName.add(title);
                                        }
                                    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {}

                               }
                        });
                } 
                catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
            return null;
        }// End of doInBackground method

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(details, Messages.this);
            msgList.setAdapter(adapter);
            pd.dismiss();
        }// End of onPostExecute method
    }.execute((Void[]) null);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use publishProgress and onProgressUpdate to post to the ui thread during the doInBackground execution.

Comment: @njzk2 actually I tried them, but not working for me, may be I coded in wrong places with wrong parameters, can you please post the answer as edited version of my code, please don't mind

Comment: Why are you coding the class inline?  move it out and give it a name then execute it in the app.. It will be easier to understand..

Comment: @Miro Markarian any way code should work right, it works, but `on click` I'm getting `Force Close`

Comment: can you post the actual stacktrace ?

Comment: @ChethanShetty  same issue i m facing can u pls tell me how u resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use `detail = new Asyntasck`. Create The Asynctask Class below and just use :

```
AsynTask myTask = new AsynTask();
myTask.execute();
```

Then your adapter is actually modified from a background thread (asynctask), exactly as the exception suggested. The solution is moving it to UI thread or simply wrapping it with runOnUiThread():

```
... ...

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    details.add(result) //use a foreach here
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(details, Messages.this);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    msgList.setAdapter(adapter);
    pd.dismiss();

  }
}); // end of runOnUiThread

... ...
```

Comment: my mistake,he anatialize his Array.

Comment: @marshallino16 How do you declare and initialize `result` while you are adding to `details` list.

Comment: @marshallino16 You can not initialize `AsyncTask` like `AsynTask myTask = new AsynTask();`

Comment: Your asynctask is a class so you can initialize an object like that and then do : `mytask.execute();`
Take a look : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example